# In Which Library IFileDialog is Located

Tags: c++, winapi

Now I'm Writing This Code

```
IFileDialog *pfd = NULL;
                HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOpenDialog, 
                  NULL, 
                  CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
                  IID_PPV_ARGS(&pfd));
```

after Compiling an Error Appeared; "IFileDialog Not Declared in this Scope"

What is The Library of that Class ??

Comment: The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775966(v=vs.85).aspx) says shobjidl.h on Vista+.

Comment: I've Tried it but The Same Error appears, 'am windows 8.1

Comment: You also need to request features for Windows Vista and above by [Setting `WINVER` or `_WIN32_WINNT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745(v=vs.85).aspx#setting_winver_or__win32_winnt).

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to know which library implements it. This is a COM interface that you invoke with a call to `CoCreateInstance`. The system does the rest. It looks up the implementing COM server in the COM registry and instantiates your object.

In order to compile you just need to include `Shobjidl.h`, and define the version macros appropriately. You need

```
#define _WINNT_WIN32 0600
```